# How can I archive a row of data? Move a row of data from one table to another, deleting the first instance, using sql and php

Tags: php, sql, netbeans, mysqli, forms

I am having trouble archiving a row of data. The user enters text - a ServerName - that is stored in the database under the column 'ServerName'. Once the button is clicked the SQL should insert that data into the new table - archive_servers - and then delete it from the original table, however, it will only delete the data and will not insert it in to the new table.
Below is my PHP connection to my database, connection checks, SQL statements to insert, select and delete and the html for the form for input.

```
<?php
$message = '';
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'isad235');
if($db->connect_error)
{
    $message = $db->connect_error;
}
else
{
    $message = 'CONNECTION OK';

    $sql = "INSERT `archive_servers` SELECT * FROM `servers` WHERE `ServerName` = '".$_POST['name']."';"; 
    echo $sql;
    $sql = "DELETE FROM `servers` WHERE `ServerName` = '".$_POST['name']."';"; 
    echo $sql;
    $result = $db->query($sql);

    if ($db->error)
    {
        echo $message = $db->error;
    }
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post"/>
            Server Name: <input type="text" name="name"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Archive"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tested the connection and it is all fine, I have echo'd the $_POST and it returns the word 'Array'.

I have probably missed something very stupid like a character that should not be there, or some other small syntax error. I am using NetBeans and it does not give me any errors when running the project. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = "INSERT `archive_servers` SELECT * FROM `servers` WHERE `ServerName` = '".$_POST['name']."';"; 
echo $sql;
$sql_delete = "DELETE FROM `servers` WHERE `ServerName` = '".$_POST['name']."';"; 
echo $sql_delete;
$result = $db->query($sql_delete);

if ($db->error)
{
    echo $message = $db->error;
}
```

With this part of code you are executing query only once.

You should execute SQL two times (for insert and delete).

This gonna do the work for you:

```
$sql_insert = "INSERT `archive_servers` SELECT * FROM `servers` WHERE `ServerName` = '".$_POST['name']."';"; 
echo $sql_insert;
$insert_result = $db->query($sql_insert);
if ($db->error)
{
    echo $message = $db->error;
}
$sql_delete = "DELETE FROM `servers` WHERE `ServerName` = '".$_POST['name']."';"; 
echo $sql_delete;
$delete_result = $db->query($sql);
if ($db->error)
{
    echo $message = $db->error;
}

if ($insert_result && $delete_result) {
  echo 'Everything ok';
}
else {
  echo 'Error occured!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing the INSERT portion.  I would also recommend checking that the insert is successful before deleting the row either via a query (slower but safer) or a simple success check.

```
$sql = "INSERT `archive_servers` SELECT * FROM `servers` WHERE `ServerName` = '".$_POST['name']."';"; 
echo $sql;
$result = $db->query($sql);
$sql = "DELETE FROM `servers` WHERE `ServerName` = '".$_POST['name']."';"; 
echo $sql;
$result = $db->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first mistake is $sql = "INSERT INTO`archive_servers` SELECT * FROM `servers` WHERE `ServerName` = '".$_POST['name']."';";